# Convert multiple arrays into 2 variables with each of their own value types

Tags: javascript

I have an API that returns an array and I need to create some charts with that data.

The issue is the way they are returned and how I map that into the chart.

The data looks like this:

```
[["United States",258],["Germany",88],["France",68]]
```

And I want to save this data into their own variable like the following:

```
var country = ["United States", "Germany", "France"]
var count = ["258", "88", "68"]
```

How can I achieve this? I wasn't sure how to explain this the correct way, so please do correct me if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it via [Array.protoype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
let apiResponse = [["United States",258],["Germany",88],["France",68]];
let countries = apiResponse.map(x => x[0])
let counts = apiResponse.map(x => x[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over the array and put the data in your arrays, something like:

```
const country = [];
const count = [];

serverArray.forEach((entry) => {
  country.push(entry[0]);
  count.push(entry[1]);
})
```

And please don't do 2 loops for something you could do in just 1 loop.

Answer (score 0):

using this:

```js
    let country = [], code = []
    let data = [["United States",258],["Germany",88],["France",68]]
    data.forEach(d => {
        country.push(d[0])
        code.push(d[1])
    })
    console.log({country, code})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a single loop. No need to use two map functions.

```
let response = [["United States",258],["Germany",88],["France",68]];

var counts = [], countries = [];
    
    response.forEach((item) => {
      countries.push(item[0]);
      counts.push(item[1]);
    });
```